# Throwing error on OpenFileDialog.Showdialog in c#.net

Tags: c#, openfiledialog, clsid

I am developing a windows application in XP machine.in my one form i have one text box for showing the selected file with path from openfiledialog box.and the other control is button to call the openfiledialog box.

When I cliked on the button to call the open dialog box i am getting the follwing error

[image: Throwing error on button clicking to open the OpenFileDialog]

rest of the form contains another controls like data grid and dropdowns.

Please help me to resolve this issue

Thanx in advance.

Regards,
Sudarshan

**Update**

Here is my code on button click

```
        OpenFileDialog  openfiledialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        openfiledialog.Filter = "xml files|*.xml";
        openfiledialog.Multiselect = false;
        DialogResult dr;
        dr = openfiledialog.ShowDialog();

        if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            txtgrdDataFile.Text = openfiledialog.FileName.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: Can you post some code related to dialog and how are you opening it?

Comment: Could you please provide your button click event's code?

Comment: What is the exact exception and where it is thrown when you debug your app?

Comment: This exception I got whenever I run the Application. I am not getting any exception if i run the application through the code in debug mode.

Comment: @Harris: If I run the application through double clicking on exe then I got this exception.

Comment: I have checked your code snippet and its working fine. Could you please add more detail to your problem?

Comment: Are you sure it is an XP machine? The stacktrace shows CreateVistaDialog()...

Comment: Yes, 2 things stand out:

1) The exception notes a reference to Vista
2) The exception notes ComInterOp

Looks like you may have your project's references screwed up. Any chance you tried to import a VB6 project?

Comment: Exception is not about ur code.How you create your project?

Comment: @LightWing : Project is simply created by visual studio IDE.Nothing added extra refrences in the project

Comment: @Abdul : Thanks for checking my code.I also checked into another program it is working fine.but in my current application if i put the same code on any form it thrown the same error.

Comment: @Rewinder :Yes It is an XP machine only

Comment: @Abdul : This is the only code I have on my button event.The functionality of the form is whenever form is.I have one ground information form.after loading the form it shows all the record of the of the ground the browse button is provided for selecting xml file related to ground information.Ones I clicked on browse button it thrown the above error.If I run this application through my code .the above executed perfectly.